# Core data migration and configurations

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to perform a migration from the 4th to the 5th version of my Core Data model.

I added a few optional relationships, one entity, and two configurations.

I tried both to specify a mapping model and to use core data, but it's failing every time with the error `Can't find model for source store`

I tried various solutions; and didn't changes my code which behaved well for previous migrations (V3 for V4, and so on...)

Most of my code is boilerplate, but I can post it here if requested.

My previous model is present in both xcode and in the simulator

I tried to use it with no configurations, and with configurations

The full error:

```
   URL = "file://localhost/Users/Antoine/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/43ABE49D-610F-4179-AE86-02ADD21BF5BD/Documents/MyApp.sqlite";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Entity1 = <74c6decf 00855ecd e7efc8d4 529f2041 c774dd75 f726ba4b 3b47dfd4 cb3c5034>;
            Entity2 = <81da9d16 fdc9eb8e f63ad9a2 ed516f84 d8bba91e 0ee550bc 38ae7c10 1ff6ea26>;
[...]

        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "D520EA63-D58C-4CAD-8310-94FEA3889C27";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "Can't find model for source store";
```

My model is provided through `[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];`
The error happen when I call `- (NSPersistentStore *)addPersistentStoreWithType:(NSString *)storeType configuration:(NSString *)configuration URL:(NSURL *)storeURL options:(NSDictionary *)options error:(NSError **)error`, with or without options, with or without configurations

Comment: Are you using a versioned model directly (which would appear in Xcode as a .xcdatamodeld, containing several separate .xcdatamodel files), or separate models?

Comment: @Tommy I use a versioned one, with the latest version selected.

Comment: Did you update the model after creating the mapping model? If so select the mapping model and choose Editor->Refresh Data Models.